# Multiple forms for entity instances - symfony3

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2

I'm trying to create a form that would allow a manager to approve a list of time off requests (also planning to have a todo list and want to be able to mark them as done).

I have read [[Generate same form type on same page multiple times Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690680/generate-same-form-type-on-same-page-multiple-times-symfony2/36557060#36557060][1]) (as well as several others) and I am close to understanding but I'm fairly to new to Symfony and not clear on what parts of the code should go in what files. I am using a form type and a controller in Symfony3 with Doctrine.

I have list of the entity instances that were returned from a query ($em->createQuery) in the controller and I am looking to produce a form for each entity instance or even two forms per entity (one for approve and one for reject).

The referenced question says you need a loop to display and save them. My intention is to only work on (submit) one at a time. I assume this part of the code would go in the controller?

I am using an indexAction for the controller but using it more like an Edit action since I will be processing forms, so I pass in a Request object and the objects as parameters.

>

```
class HRMgrController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all manager role requests and provide a means to approve/deny.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="hrmgr_index")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_APP_MANAGER')")
     */    
public function indexAction(Request $request, TimeOffRequest $timeOffRequest)
{
    if (!empty($timeOffRequest)) {
            $form = $this->createForm('CockpitBundle\Form\TORApprovalType', $timeOffRequest);
        print "TOR Id = " . $timeOffRequest->getId() . "<BR>";
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        print "Form name = " . $form->getName() . "<BR>";
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if ($form->get('approve')->isClicked()) {
                print "This puppy was approved";
                $timeOffRequest['status'] = 4;
            }
            if ($form->get('reject')->isClicked()) {
                print "This puppy was rejected";
                $timeOffRequest['status'] = 1;
            }
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
            print "At least its there<BR>";
            // return $this->redirectToRoute('hrmgr_index');
        } else {
            print "did not detect form submission<BR>";
        }
    } 

    $emp = new \CockpitBundle\Entity\Employee();

    $date = new \DateTime();
    $year = $date->format('Y');
    $username = $this->getUser()->getUserName();
    $user = $em->getRepository('CockpitBundle:Employee')->findByUsername($username);
    $employees = $em->getRepository('CockpitBundle:Employee')->htmlContact($user);
    $tors = $em->getRepository('CockpitBundle:TimeOffRequest')->findMgrUnapprovedTORs($user->getId());
    $timeoff = "<h3>Unapproved Time Off Requests</h3>";
    $actions = true;

    $torforms = [];
    foreach ($tors as $tor) {
        $target = $this->generateUrl('hrmgr_index',array("tor_id" => $tor->getId()));
        $torforms[] = $this->actionForm($tor,$target)->createView();
    }
    return $this->render('hrmgr/index.html.twig', array(
        'torforms' => $torforms,
    ));
```

I have the forms working nowbut when I submit them the isSubmitted() doesn't seem to be working. It outputs the "did not detect form submission" currently.

So when I have multiple forms and I submit one, does the handleRequest get the right one? I think I might be confusing two concepts here as well. I recently changed the code to submit the ID of the timeOffRequest as a parameter to the route. It is properly picking that up which allows me to potentially update the form but that part of the code doesn't seem to be working.

I noticed that if I look at the debugger, I get something like:

```
>   approval_form_2 
   [▼
     "reject" => ""
     "_token" => "IE1rGa5c0vaJYk74_ncxgFsoDU7wWlkAAWWjLe3Jr1w"
   ]
```

if I click the reject button. I get a similar form with "approve" if I click the approve button so it seems like I am close. Also, the proper ID shows up from the route given in the action.

Here is the form generator:

```
<?php

namespace CockpitBundle\Form;


use CockpitBundle\Entity\Employee;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class TORApprovalType extends AbstractType
{

    private $nameSuffix = null;
    private $name = 'time_req_approval';
    public function __constructor(string $suffix = null)   {
        //parent::__construct();

        $this->nameSuffix = $this->generateNameSuffix();
    }

    private function generateNameSuffix() {
        if ($this->nameSuffix == null ||  $this->nameSuffix == '') {
            $generator = new SecureRandom();
            //change data to alphanumeric string
            return bin2hex($generator->nextBytes(10));
        }

        return $this->nameSuffix;
    }
    public function setNameSuffix($suffix){
        $this->nameSuffix = $suffix;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Build your form...
        $builder->add('approve', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => "Approve",
            'attr' => array("class"=>"action-approve"),
        ));
        $builder->add('reject', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => "Reject",
            'attr' => array("class"=>"action-reject"),
        ));
        //$builder->add('employee');

    }
    public function getName()    {
        if ($this->nameSuffix == null || $this->nameSuffix == "" ) {
            $this->nameSuffix = $this->generateNameSuffix();
        }
        return $this->name .'_'. $this->nameSuffix;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CockpitBundle\Entity\TimeOffRequest'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'cockpitbundle_timeoffrequest';
    }


}
```

Any clues? (sorry I am on vacation so not particular quick with updates.

Comment: The way you're doing it would be one form that has 2 submit buttons, one called `approve` and the other one `reject`. That would be totally fine, but I think that your a bit confused by syntax and the usage of multiple forms. Can you please provide the code of the `TimeOffRequestType`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple submit button: check your formtype

```
    ->add('approve', 'submit')
    ->add('reject', 'submit')
```

then in your controller

```
 if ($form->isValid()) {
        // ... do something

        // the save_and_add button was clicked
        if ($form->get('approve')->isClicked()) {
            // probably redirect to the add page again
        }
        if ($form->get('reject')->isClicked()) {
            // probably redirect to the add page again
        }

        // redirect to the show page for the just submitted item
    }
```

Comment: I'm creating a TORApprovalType file (different than the CRUD edit) that would generate the desired form. I need it to be able to create multiple forms that will be displayed on the same page.

Comment: can you give more details ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with the following builder.

```
   $builder->add('approve', SubmitType::class, array(
        'label' => "Approve",
        'attr' => array("class"=>"action-approve"),
    ));
    $builder->add('reject', SubmitType::class, array(
        'label' => "Reject",
        'attr' => array("class"=>"action-reject"),
    ));
```

Then in the controller form I generate and process the forms as such. Not sure if it is the optimal way but it works find. Of course, this approach redraws the whole list each time, but that is fine for what I'm doing.

```
class HRMgrController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all manager role requests and provide a means to approve/deny.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="manager_home")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_APP_MANAGER')")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $emp = new \CockpitBundle\Entity\Employee();
        $employeeSummary = [];
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $year = $date->format('Y');
        $username = $this->getUser()->getUserName();
        $user = $em->getRepository('CockpitBundle:Employee')->findByUsername($username);
        $myemployees = $em->getRepository('CockpitBundle:Employee')->findManagersEmployees($user);
        $torRep = $em->getRepository('CockpitBundle:TimeOffRequest');
        $toas = [];
        $torforms = [];
        foreach ($myemployees as $employee) {
            $tors = $torRep->findAllMine($employee,$year);
            $toas[$employee->getDisplayName()] = $em->getRepository('CockpitBundle:TimeOffAllocation')->getEmpAllocation($employee->getId(),$year);
            $employeeSummary[$employee->getDisplayName()] = $torRep->mySummary($tors,$toas[$employee->getDisplayName()]);
            if (array_key_exists('items',$employeeSummary[$employee->getDisplayName()]['Vacation']['Requested'])) {
                foreach ($employeeSummary[$employee->getDisplayName()]['Vacation']['Requested']['items'] as $tor) {
                    $target = $this->generateUrl('hrmgr_tor_approval',array("tor_id" => $tor->getId()));
                    $torforms[] = $this->actionForm($tor,$target)->createView();
                }
            }
            if (array_key_exists('items',$employeeSummary[$employee->getDisplayName()]['Sick Time']['Requested'])) {
                foreach ($employeeSummary[$employee->getDisplayName()]['Sick Time']['Requested']['items'] as $tor) {
                    $target = $this->generateUrl('hrmgr_tor_approval',array("tor_id" => $tor->getId()));
                    $torforms[] = $this->actionForm($tor,$target)->createView();
                }
            }
            if (array_key_exists('Time Off',$employeeSummary[$employee->getDisplayName()]) && 
                    array_key_exists('items',$employeeSummary[$employee->getDisplayName()]['Time Off']['Requested'])) {
                foreach ($employeeSummary[$employee->getDisplayName()]['Time Off']['Requested']['items'] as $tor) {
                    $target = $this->generateUrl('hrmgr_tor_approval',array("tor_id" => $tor->getId()));
                    $torforms[] = $this->actionForm($tor,$target)->createView();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('hrmgr/index.html.twig', array(
            'employeeSummary' => $employeeSummary,
            'torforms' => $torforms,
            'year' => $year,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Lists all manager role requests and provide a means to approve/deny.
     *
     * @Route("/{tor_id}", name="hrmgr_tor_approval")
     * @Method({ "POST" })
     * @ParamConverter("timeOffRequest", class="CockpitBundle:TimeOffRequest", options={"id"="tor_id"})
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_APP_MANAGER')")
     */
    public function approvalAction(Request $request, TimeOffRequest $timeOffRequest)
    {
        if (!empty($timeOffRequest)) {
            $form = $this->createForm('CockpitBundle\Form\TORApprovalType', $timeOffRequest);
            $id = $timeOffRequest->getId();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            $postparams = $request->request->all();

            if (array_key_exists("approval_form_$id",$postparams)) {
                // Form was submitted
                if (array_key_exists("approve",$postparams["approval_form_$id"])) {
                    $status = $em->getReference('CockpitBundle\Entity\TimeOffStatus', 4);
                    $timeOffRequest->setStatus($status);
                    $timeOffRequest->setApprovedDate(new \DateTime);
                    $em->persist($timeOffRequest);
                    $em->flush($timeOffRequest);
                }
                if (array_key_exists("reject",$postparams["approval_form_$id"])) {
                    $status = $em->getReference('CockpitBundle\Entity\TimeOffStatus', 1);
                    $timeOffRequest->setStatus($status);
                    $timeOffRequest->setApprovedDate(new \DateTime);
                    $em->persist($timeOffRequest);
                    $em->flush($timeOffRequest);
                }
            } else {
                print "Form did not exist<BR>";
            }
            return $this->redirectToRoute('manager_home');
        } 
    }
    public function actionForm($tor,$target) {
        return $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('approval_form_'.$tor->getId(), \CockpitBundle\Form\TORApprovalType::class, $tor,
             array("action"=> $target))->getForm();        
    }
}
```